# set of points of continuity is dense in $Baire$

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let X be $Baire$ space and $(Y,d)$ a metric space. Let $f_n:X\to Y$ continuous maps that converge pointwise to $f:X\to Y$.

Prove that the set of points which $f$ is continuous in them is dense in $X$.

Comment: See https://www.math.ucsd.edu/programs/undergraduate/1213_honors_presentations/Siuyung_Fung_Honors_Thesis.pdf